# Scilab - for loop - finding matching data points - from matrices of different lengths - index error

Tags: data-analysis, scilab

Within Scilab I am trying to find data points (time) that match then index these points (a1 continous, a2 discreet events). I can take this index to select data points from other data sets so then I can analyse data based on the discreet events (a2).

The below code gives me an 'index error' on this line 'if a1(i) == a2(j);'

```
    a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
    a2 = [3,4,6,8,10,12]

    x = 0

    for i = x:length(a1);
        for j = 0:length(a2);
            if a1(i) == a2(j);
                disp(x)
            end
        end
    end
```

If there are any proficient Scilab users out there to help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the intersect function. It does exactly what you want in an efficient way

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes this function looks like it will do exactly what I have written. My code is now fully working with f(x) = i within the 'if' statement to produce the index matrix and then I filter all the 0 values values and then wanted_data = all_data(index_data) for processing. Next time I approach this problem I think I will just  use the intersect function :)

Comment: Just to add to this, the intersect function is much much faster than my code for anyone who ever happens to read this thread use the intersect function.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. The invalid index was due to the matrix not having a zero index.

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
a2 = [3,4,6,8,10,12]

x = 1;

for i = 1:13;
        for j = x:6;
        if a1(i) == a2(j);
            disp(a2(j))
            x = j
        end
    end
end
```